# "A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of null"

Tags: java, json

Just wondering what that error could mean? I get it from the following code..

```
 try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                    ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                    ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                    ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
            );
    }
}
}catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us the actual line of code of the exception?

Comment: try to use Gson for parsing Json into POJO ojects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Result is null, apparently. Or it simply does not start with `[`. Print it out before calling JSONArray to see.

Also take a look at the [JSONArray source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20080701/org/json/JSONArray.java). It is expecting JavaScript array syntax, e.g.:

`['this', 'is', 'array', 'syntax']`

Answer (score 1):

`text.trim(); text.trim();`

Text is the json file or string , do this at least two times one after another will resolve the problem 99.9%.