# Result cannot be converted to JSON Array

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to return data from MYSQL database in my android app, but when i run the application the returned result cannot be converted to JSON Array "an exception occurred saying that JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"

I ensure that the php script returns the data in JSON format and the result before parsing it isnt null, it holds the returned data. Why does this exception occur and how i can solve it ? please help me

**this is my code:**

```
       private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> { 

 private String result = "";
 private InputStream is = null;

 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;



protected void onPreExecute() 
{
       this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AddFood.this, "","Loading......");  
}

@Override
            protected String  doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                 MealActivity.foodList = new ArrayList<ItemInList>();     

   try
   {
          ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",entered_food_Name));
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/food.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      is = entity.getContent();
       }
   catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
      }
//convert response to string
   try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
   Log.e("log_tag",result+ "result");
    return result;
    }


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String  result) 
                   {
                              this.progressDialog.dismiss();

    try{
         Log.e("log_tag", " result before parsing " + result);

         String foodName="";
         int Description=0;

         JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

             foodName=json_data.getString("Name");
             Description=json_data.getInt("Calories");              
             item.setName(foodName);
             item.setDescription(Description);
             item.setSelected(false);
             MealActivity.foodList.add(item);   
                                                             }

                                                                 }
            catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "parssing error " + e.toString());
            }   

    }}
```

**this is the php script :**

```
<?php

 $con1=mysql_connect("localhost" , "user","pass" ) ;

 mysql_select_db("MYDB");
 mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); 

 $sql=mysql_query("select  Name,Calories  from food where Name LIKE      '%".$_REQUEST['Name']."%' ");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
$data =json_encode($output);
print($data);
mysql_close();

  ?>
```

**returned Data**

```
  E/log_tag(491):  result before parsing             [{"Name":"\u0627\u0641\u0648\u0643\u0627\u062f\u0648","Calories":"160"}]
```

Comment: Can you post the data that gets printed from the print($data) call? It's really hard to tell what the problem is before seeing this data.

Comment: I post  it , yo can see it now

Comment: please help me , iam new in android , how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what we'd need to see; can you just give us the output of your PHP script? For example, if you call it from your browser?

Comment: it gives the same result

Comment: i means that it gives me output as the data that i post it

Comment: `{"Name":"\u0627\u0641\u0648\u0643\u0627\u062f\u0648","Calories":"160","Fiber":"7"}` is _all_ the output that you get?

Comment: you have any idea about what i can do to solve the parsing problem?

Comment: OK, I never write code for Android, but it [looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3085839/1185355) that's a `JSONObject` in Android, not a `JSONArray`. Android JSONArrays look like this: `['this', 'is', 'array', 'syntax']`. So try using `JSONObject` instead.

Comment: Given your output I can create a JSONArray without issue.

Comment: Hmm. If that's the case, there may be some invisible control characters messing up your data? Maybe you're encoding the PHP file as UTF-8 with a BOM? Try encoding the file as UTF-8 without BOM and ensure it's not sending any other output than the output produced by `json_decode`.

Comment: Daan its returned as a JSON Array  , see what i was posted above its in a JSON format ,i print the  returned data in the log but it cant be parsed

Comment: what did you mean by  BOM  ?  since  iam new in php , how i can do that? and thanks for helping me

Comment: That's actually a setting of your text editor. Look for "encoding" in the settings of your text editor and ensure that's set to UTF-8 without BOM (and a BOM is a byte-order mark; Google will tell you all you'd ever care to know about them).

Answer (score 2):

you can make your code look simpler by using:

```
String jsonStr = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

to get String from entity.

What looks suspicious it this long gap between 'parsing' and opening brace : '[', it looks like there are some control characters inside. Here are some hints on this:

1. Make sure you are writing your php file using ASCII encoding, probably your HTML editor is adding BOM mark at the begining of .php file.
2. Make sure there are no characters outside <?php and ?> markings
3. To verify what bad characters are in results string, output them to log as bytes, UTF-8 BOM looks as follows: 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF

otherwise your json parsing looks fine

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql=mysql_query("select  Name as name,Calories as cal  from food where Name LIKE      '%".$_REQUEST['Name']."%' ");
```

Just Few Changes And your problem will be sorted out .

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

$name=$row['name'];

$cal=$row['cal'];

$data1 =json_encode($name);

$data2=json_encode($cal);

print($data1);
print($data2);
```